# Nested ids in REST API url

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

Say a user does a `GET` to return all the services for a company by using the following url: `/api/company/{id}/service`

They then want to update one of the service objects that are returned. Should I follow the same convention and so get them to `PUT` to `/api/company/{id}/service/{id}` or make it a bit simpler and just get them to do `PUT` to `/api/service/{id}` as the service id is globally unique.

One reason I was doing the longer URL is that I want to check if the user belongs to the Company so I can easily check that upon the request as I have the Company Id but if I go the direct route I'd then have to find the Company Id from the service and check that.

I've had a quick search and couldn't see any obvious about what the standard is for this.

Thanks

Comment: This is something that will bring a lot of debates, but there isn't any "standard" that I am aware of. Either or both of those are just fine; I've done designs that would allow access from both URLs simultaneously as well as designs that would use one or the other.

Comment: It does not matter whether the service id is unique or not. All that matters is whether the service is owned by the company. If yes(which i think it is) then you should stick with /api/company/{id}/service/{id}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think every answer to this kind of question is a little bit debatable because the two approaches you proposed are conceptually both correct, anyway I will try to answer.

In my opinion you have to decide starting from the relationship between your `company` resource and your `service` resource. If a `service` is exclusively owned by a single `company` then I would go for the more verbose path `/api/company/{id}/service/{id}`. If, instead, your `service` resources are shared among different `company` resources, then I would prefer the shorter and global `/api/service/{id}` path.

The reasons behind my choices are purely conventional, and aim to clarify how the two resources interact each other in the application domain.

Comment: A service is owned exclusively by a single company so I'm going to go for the longer route as you suggested. This also makes it easier for me to check authorization as I know the company id and service id from the url and also the user id from ASP.Net Identity so I can do a simple select with just the url parameters

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can cut back the URI using only the ids, for example:

> POST /api/{companyId}/{serviceId}

You will have something like this:

> POST /api/movistar/balance
>      POST /api/movistar/sales

Answer (score 0):

First, make your clients follow links, instead of distributing "templates" how to call specific things. (Maybe you are already doing this, it is not clear from your post).

That is, when they `GET` the resource that lists all the services, you should include links to those services (whatever they are). This way your clients will need to `PUT` to the URI you supply. This way, you are in full control of the URI structure.

This in turn means, that you can use whatever structure is more convenient for you, since it will be transparent for the clients anyway. If you are more comfortable including both IDs in the URI, then go ahead. You can even change it later, if you don't like it, without the clients noticing!